# Why were the first 6 episodes skipped?

Tags: dragon-ball-gt

When the english version of Dragon Ball GT was released to the US, the first 6 episodes were skipped and replaced with a composite episode.  Why were these 6 episodes skipped and compressed into one episode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess its 16 rather than 6, From the posts I have been reading [about](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Star_Dragon_Ball_Saga) it seems that Dragon Ball GT which was set 5 years after Dragon Ball Z tried to start off in a similar tone to the original Dragon Ball  by trying to be less serious and more funny but the reception was very poor for those initial 16 episodes which forced FUNimation the company that produced GT to compress them as a recap and start off directly at the 17th episode.

> **The excerpt from the dragonball wiki** The Black Star Dragon Ball Saga is the introductory arc of the Dragon Ball GT series, taking place 5 (according to the Daizenshuu)/10 (according to the FUNimation Dub) years after the end of Dragon Ball Z. This is also the part of the series that tried to recapture the spirit of Dragon Ball with its more comical adventurous tone rather than the serious nature of Dragon Ball Z. Due to this, many fans were disappointed, so FUNimation had cut the first 16 episodes of this saga and began Dragon Ball GT with episode 17.